# Maintaining production login credentials secure

Tags: java

We have login credentials for our database stored in some config file which checked into codebase repository. Generally we would have development credentials in dev environment and that would be checked in. While deploying in production, one would replace it with production login credentials manually.

I wish to know what are the best practices to keep things secure. Are we doing the right thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the app create its own database connections consider using a `DataSource` accessible using JNDI. This removes the credentials from the application completely and moves the problem into how do you secure your `DataSource` in JNDI? This generally makes the problem a lot easier to solve. For example if your `DataSource` is configured on the application server that your app is deployed to, then its secured already by the authentication system used to secure the app server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely keep your production credentials out of source control.

Lock down the production user account so that only that user can see/change the config file, e.g. on unix the permissions should be

-rw-------

Even the directory it's in should be off-limits to unauthorised users.

Restrict access to the production server: as few user accounts as possible, auditing, physical access restrictions such as locked server room, etc.

Edit: to clarify, my rationale for suggesting keep credentials out of source control is that often, especially in larger companies, production credentials are not permitted to be known/used by a development team.  In some places a developer even logging into a production DB could be a sacking offense. Especially if they then break something!

Also, developers in other teams/depts may have source control access and this could be seen to substantially compromise the production DB.  Of course if you're a 3 man dev organisation this is less of a concern.

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is internal and not shared with anyone that should not have access to these credentials, your approach is ok.

However, things can change and in these matters it pays to be paranoid. What I usually do is to keep an empty skeleton config-file (with a different extension or something) in the source control, and then have the source-control ignore the proper configuration file. This way it's not overwritten when deploying a new version from the source-control.

Also Brians suggestion to keep things as restricted as possible is good advice!